# How do I create a custom raycast with VRTK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, vrtk

I am trying to create a custom tracer and a custom cursor for the raycast. 
Using the options given by the VR Pointer in the inspector don't seem to work.

I want to have a shaded tracer with my own material. Same for the cursor.

How do I do it?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ask in the VRTK slack

Comment: I have tried using the custom tracer and custom cursor fields in the VR Pointer script and associating to that other objects but the cursor won't change